# How can I make my Python script a system command and run it easily in any directory in Windows?

Tags: python, windows

I am a Python rookie and I learn Python3.3 in Windows.

I wrote my first script, a script to rename files with incremental filenames. But by now, I had to copy my `rename.py` script to the directory I want to change the files names and run `Python rename.py`. It is not a very fancy way to use.

I can improve my code and pass the target directory to run my script in origin directory like `Python rename.py .../TargetDir`, but I have to copy the directory everytime.

So I want to make my script a system command, then I would only type `rename` in cmd.exe in the directory I want to rename a bunch of files. How can I approach this.

Comment: Instead of passing the target directory as an argument, you can simply use `os.getcwd()` (assuming the working directory does not change before this function is executed).

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, you'll want to use `doskey`, which allows you to set aliases for commands.

You use it like this:

```
doskey macroName=macroDefinition
```

So you would want to write something like this:

```
doskey rename=Python rename.py .
```

Where the `.` stands for the directory you're currently in. (I wasn't exactly clear on what you wanted -- the way I read your question was that you just want to `cd` into the directory where you want to rename a bunch of files, then run the script.)

Answer (score 1):

Use sys.argv to get the command line arguments. For example `test.py`:

```
import os
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]
print(os.listdir(path))
```

and then you can create a batch file which should placed in a folder that belongs to the `PATH` variable. In order to do so, create a text document with the following contents and save it as `ListDir.bat`. Copy the ListDir.bat to either your python folder, or Windows folder (both should be in your `PATH`)

ListDir.bat:

```
python C:\test.py "%CD%"
PAUSE
```

The `%CD%` refers to the current directory in the windows prompt. So assuming the python script `test.py` is in `C:\` the first line executes the test.py script with the argument current directory.

I used `PAUSE` to get user input before completing the script, you could choose not to.

After you save the `ListDir.bat` file. You can navigate to the folder you want to use it in, and just call `ListDir`